# What to do when program is larger than 512 bytes in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I made a basic operating system which have calculator, file manager, paint and much more but my program in assembly is larger than 512 bytes. I think that here is my problem in :

```
times 510d - ($ - $$)  db 0
dw 0AA55h
```

Comment: This only applies to freestanding programs loaded as a boot sector, not to asm programs in general.  But in your case, write code to load more sectors from disk.

Comment: an OS doesn't have that small size

Comment: A paint application or calculator should probably not be a part of your boot sector, or of the OS in general. Let them be _applications_ that can be loaded by the OS.

Comment: We can't answer this question but with an advice. Make a [mcve] so we can work on that.

Answer (score 2):

Put everything below the `dw 0aa55h`,

And above `times 510-($-$$) db 0`,

Put code that load more sector and jump to loaded memory.

The interruput number you may want to know is 0x13(ah = 2)

You may able to read example from https://github.com/icebreaker/floppybird/blob/master/src/boot.asm